# Double email or email triggers twice for automated actions

Tags: email, duplicates, odoo-10

I am using Odoo 10. I have created Automated Action on purchase order update. And there is a condition field in action, so I gave the condition like this object.state=="to approve" . Everything works perfectly only that the mail triggers twice. That is I am getting two same emails whenever the above mentioned codition is satisfied. How can I avoid double emails to occur? I read many comments and solutions but didnt see a clear answer or solution for this. If anyone have solved this please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste your code, might be issue with looping

Comment: Dear no code its automated action under technical settings. In the body content also no code just a plain message. And as I have mentioned in the question there is a field with name condition, there I have given this object.state=="to approve"